# Is there a guide to changing emacs colorscheme?

Tags: emacs

In the terminal when I try to use emacs the colors are not good, most of the times I can't properly see the text.

In vim I know I can change the colorscheme with `:colo <colorscheme_name>`

Is there something similar in emacs?
A tutorial on the proper steps to change the colors would be appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Emacs are you running. (You can achieve this in any vaguely recent Emacs, but Emacs 24 does have some default abilities in this area.)

Comment: @skeept: *color-theme-zenburn* FTW.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure of tutorial, but off top of my head, what you probably will want to do is: `M-x customize` then navigate to the section called "Faces" - you'll get a bunch of settings related to the color scheme and other font-related settings.

But Emacs has tons of customizations related to how text is displayed. I'm using this http://www.nongnu.org/color-theme/ but you can find a lot of info here: http://emacswiki.org/emacs/ColorTheme (emacswiki is basically *the* resource to be consulted first when you have any Emacs-related problem).

Obviously, you can do that in your .emacs file by adding different settings, but I'd suggest to use what's generated by the changed settings first, see how it works and then add on top of that yourself (once you modify settings from the customization buffer, it will save the changes into .emacs file - you can then open it and see what exactly did it do).

Comment: You almost certainly don't need to delve into the customize menus unless you need very fine-grained control. For Emacs 23 or less, the color-theme package you referenced is what OP needs. If you're on Emacs 24, there's a built-in replacement: just do "M-x load-theme" and you should be able to tab-complete a few standard themes to find one that fits.

Comment: The load-theme function is very useful, I now figured out that the reason the colorshemes looked so bad is because of the terminal settings. When  I run `TERM=xterm-256color emacs` instead of just emacs, the colorschemes look quite good and I can actually see the text. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
M-x load-theme
```

then use arrows to select a theme.

*Adding here for easy reference ( @deong shared this answer via comment under the accepted answer).*